# MS BotBuilder on Azure

Tags: botframework

Deploying botbuilder on azure is fine.

But when invoked from botframework I get the internal server error.
Log files show this error in the stack trace of application log.

```
 builder.ChatConnector is not a constructor.
```

Anything to be done to solve this?

Comment: Do you have the `botbuilder` dependency installed? Does your bot work locally?

Answer (score 0):

Redeoploying the application to a new azure site did the trick.